# How to find a complex string in a file containing characters that need to be escaped in the search/replace parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I would like to search for this exact string (quotes, brackets, ampersands and all) in a file but have apparently been unable to escape the string correctly so I could get a match:

```
this._name='Search',this._url='https://www.google.com/search?q={keywords}&client=firefox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8',"
```

My attempts so far include:

```
Select-String -Path "C:\textfile.txt" -Pattern 'this._name=''Search'',this._url=''https://www.google.com/search?q={keywords}&client=firefox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8'',"'
Select-String -Path "C:\textfile.txt" -Pattern "this._name='Search',this._url='https://www.google.com/search?q={{keywords{{&client=firefox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8',`""
```

and some variations of this (including escaping the forward slashes by using backslashes), none of which produce a match.
(The textfile is a simple one created in notepad which contains only the first string above, copy and pasted just  to be sure).

I've also tried

```
$stuff = Get-Content -Path 'C:\textfile.txt'
$newstuff = $stuff -replace '[String above in various escape variations]'
```

(which I might want to use eventually) to see if it behaves differently, but no luck.

Also, formatting/escaping strings like these manually takes an awful lot of time (and is obviously prone to mistakes). Is there a command or tool one can use to generate fully-escaped strings quickly for use with single- and/or double-quoted strings in PowerShell?

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You could use the `.Escape` method of the `[REGEX]` class to help you .... `[REGEX]::Escape('SampleString')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must escape special regex characters `.`, `?`, and `{`. The Regex class method `Escape()` can do this for you. Second, you need to properly handle inner quotes. Any inner quotes that could prematurely close outer quotes need to be escaped. You can just double up those quotes for the escape.

```
$pattern = [regex]::Escape('this._name=''Search'',this._url=''https://www.google.com/search?q={keywords}&client=firefox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8'',"')
Select-String -Path C:\textfile.txt -Pattern $pattern
```